# Binning and transforming in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe below.

```
A  B
1  1
4  1
5  1
6  2
8  3
15 4
```

I would like to binning and transform dataframe to below.

```
range(A) sum(B)
[0,4)    2
[5,9)    6
[10,14)  0
[15,19)  4
```

I tried `groupby+Grouper`, but I couldnt figure out how to bin.

Can I ask how to transform data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) with parameters `right=False` for not include right bins with `groupby`:

Thank you [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953865/binning-and-transforming-in-pandas/41954057#comment71087375_41954057) for idea add parameter `labels`.

```
print (pd.cut(df['A'], 
              bins=[0, 5, 10, 15, 20], 
              labels=['[0,4)', '[5,9)', '[10,14)', '[15,19)'], 
              right=False))
0      [0,4)
1      [0,4)
2      [5,9)
3      [5,9)
4      [5,9)
5    [15,19)
Name: A, dtype: category

df = df.groupby([pd.cut(df['A'], bins=[0, 5, 10, 15, 20], 
                        labels=['[0,4)', '[5,9)', '[10,14)', '[15,19)'], 
                        right=False)])
       .B.sum()
       .fillna(0)
       .reset_index()

df.columns = ['range(A)','sum(B)']
print (df)
  range(A)  sum(B)
0    [0,4)     2.0
1    [5,9)     6.0
2  [10,14)     0.0
3  [15,19)     4.0
```

Comment: You could add `labels=` to `pd.cut` for desired labeling as well -- `pd.cut(df.A, [0, 5, 10, 15, 20], right=False, labels=['[0,4)', '[5,9)', '[10,14)', '[15,19)'])`

Comment: @JohnGalt - very nice idea, give me a sec.