# How to assign integer value from bins

Tags: python, python-3.x, binning

I am trying to find a pythonic way to assign a numeric value depending on where a variable falls in. That is:

```
variable = 23
if variable < -100:
    return_value = -15
elif variable <= -5:
    return_value = -4
elif variable <= 5:
    return_value = 18
else:
    return_value = 88
```

I could of course create a list containing the buckets/values and iterate through and return when the correct value is found:

```
bucket_values = [(-100, -15), (-5, -4), (5, 18)]
default = 88
variable = 100
for lower_bound, value in bucket_values:
    if variable < lower_bound:
        return_value = value
        break
else:
    return_value = default
```

But then I need to check for lower and upper bounds and equality i.e. If it is the first iteration of the loop I must check if inferior (<), then the next loop I must check for inferior & equal (<=).

I am looking for something like this (Ruby):

```
buckets = [
[:<, -90, -57], 
[:<=, 5, -10], 
[:<=, 10, 3], 
[:>, 60, 40]] 

# Pass bucket to a method
```

My question is: 
**Is there a pythonic way of doing this with variable bounds and values?**

Comment: I am not sure what a good question title might be for this problem. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029245/putting-an-if-elif-else-statement-on-one-line)... I don't know if this is what you're looking for

Comment: What is the code you are thinking about in the first place? If you could add that one to the question w could help to translate it to Python.

Comment: @Anwarvic I am not looking for an if else. Because this forces the amount of buckets.

Comment: @TobiasWilfert In ruby I could do the same with this:

buckets = [
          [:<, -90, -57],
          [:<=, 5, -10],
          [:<=, 10, 3],
          [:>, 60, 40]
        ]

And then pass this to a method. Anything similar in python?

Comment: If you write exact Ruby equivalent in your question, it may be easier to find somethind similar in Python, also are your numbers only integers or they can also be floats?

Comment: @unlut Only integers in my case. I edited my question to add the ruby bucket.

Comment: This is called **binning** and there are many existing solutions on SO. Can you use `pandas` library, it has `pd.cut()` ? [Binning and transforming in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953865/binning-and-transforming-in-pandas)

Comment: @smci From my understanding pd.cut() will separate into bins, but I do not see lower, upper bounds i.e. if i create bins [0, 10, 20], it will create 2 bins [0 - 10] and [10-20] but nothing for say [-inf - 0] nor [20 - inf]. I will look further if I am wrong. But this is the kind of answer I am looking for!

Comment: @JuBonn: usually that's the case of discrete bins that are adjacent, hence the top of bin (n-1) is the bottom of bin n. But you want disjoint bins. You could include the missing bins too, then afterwards map illegal/missing bin values to whatever you want. Btw, np.NINF, np.PINF are legal bin values.

Comment: @smci this is the answer I was looking for! Therefore a combination of pd and np.ninf/np.inf.

Comment: Do you want a basic Python solution (using `operator.ge/gt/lt/le`), or a pandas+numpy solution (using `pd.cut`), or don't-care which? Do you want your output to be the bottom value of the containing bin, or a categorical corresponding to the number of the bin, or you don't-care which?

Comment: @smci Gonna verify with the rest of the codebase. Don't want to add too many dependencies. I think that both are valid answers to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple with the module `operator`. Here's an example:

```
>>> import operator
>>> bucket = (operator.ge, -100, operator.le, -5)
>>> def in_bucket(value, bucket): return bucket[0](value, bucket[1]) and bucket[2](value, bucket[3])
...
>>> in_bucket(-101, bucket)
False
>>> in_bucket(-100, bucket)
True
>>> in_bucket(-5, bucket)
True
>>> in_bucket(-4, bucket)
False
```

But you can do better, by defining a more generic structure:

```
>>> conditions = ((operator.ge, -100), (operator.le, -5))
>>> def match_conditions(value, conditions): return all(c[0](value, c[1]) for c in conditions)
...
>>> match_conditions(-101, conditions)
False
>>> match_conditions(-100, conditions)
True
>>> match_conditions(-5, conditions)
True
>>> match_conditions(-4, conditions)
False
```

The `all` operator returns true iff all conditions are met. The key difference between `bucket` and `conditions` is that you can add conditions that do not concern boundaries, e.g value must be pair:

```
>>> conditions = ((operator.ge, -100), (operator.le, -5), (lambda v, _: v%2==0, None))
>>> match_conditions(-7, conditions)
False
>>> match_conditions(-6, conditions)
True
>>> match_conditions(-5, conditions)    
False
```

Now you can use a dictionary to summarize your conditions (first example you gave) :

```
>>> value_by_conditions = { 
... ((operator.lt, -100),): -15,
... ((operator.ge, -100), (operator.le, -5)): -4,
... ((operator.gt, -5), (operator.le, 5)): 18,
... ((operator.gt, 5),): 88,
... }
>>> next((v for cs, v in value_by_conditions.items() if match_conditions(23, cs)), None)
88
>>> next((v for cs, v in value_by_conditions.items() if match_conditions(-101, cs)), None)
-15
>>> next((v for cs, v in value_by_conditions.items() if match_conditions(-100, cs)), None)
-4
```

Notes:

1. I used tuples since lists are not hashable (and thus can't be used as dict keys) ;
2. `next((x for x in xs if <test>), None)` takes the first element in `xs` that passes the test. If no elements passes the test, it returns the default value `None` ;
3. You have, in older versions of Python (< 3.7), no guarantee for the order of the tests. It's important if you have overlapping conditions.
4. This is clearly suboptimal, because you test if `value < 100` then if `value >= 100`, etc.

Is this really pythonic? I'm, not so sure. Have a look at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ to make your own idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty pythonic, but I don't recommend it

```
>>> variable = 23
>>> return_value = -5 if variable<-100 else -4  if variable<=-4 else 18 if variable<= 5  else 88
>>> print(return_value)
88
```

Notice that `88` is the default value.

### **EDIT**

you can create a function that is based on the same concept as `if... else` shown above. The function would be something like this:

```
def pythonic(variable, bucket_values, default):
    for k,v in bucket_values:
        return_value = v if variable<k else "---"
        if return_value != "---":
            return return_value
    return default
```

You can use it like so:

```
>>> variable = 23
>>> bucket_values = [(-100, -15), (-5, -4), (5, 18)]
>>> print(pythonic(variable, bucket_values, 88))
88

>>> variable = 1
>>> print(pythonic(variable, bucket_values, 88))
18
```

Comment: I am looking for a way with variable values and bounds. Therefore an IF-Else does not work for me.

Comment: @JuBonn, I edited my answer, I hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, for every "bucket" you have an interval. To check if value belongs to some interval you could define a function:

```
def check_value(value, interval):
    if value in range(interval[0], interval[1]+1):
        print('Value ', value)
        print('Interval ', interval)
    else:
        pass
```

Now just iterate over a list of intervals to find where value belongs:

```
for interval in list_of_intervals:
    check_value(value, interval)
```

Comment: This would be equivalent to the pd.cut() function mentionned by @smci. And it doesnt include lower and upper bounds.